# How do I set a char to the hex value of an int variable?

Tags: c++

Say I have an

```
int i = 10;
```

How do I assign a `char c` to `0xA`?

Comment: A `char` represents **one** character of text. Since you are using C++, you presumably want a `std::string` instance.

Answer (score 3):

The decimal `10` and hex `0xA` are the same value internally, so you simply assign it directly:

```
int i = 10;
char c = i;
```

Comment: Don't confuse values, like ten, the number of fingers you have, with representations of values, like "10", "ten", or "0x0A" (which all represent the same value).